# How to Store JSON Response in a Model Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to show car data in tableview , and there is 2 type of history model. As you can see in my response 1st object of car have history and other object have None. 
How to make Structure of History json model in structure of VehicalModel , how to access that model and map with the help of alamofire. And How to check the history is available or not if available then store in model and show in tableview.

This is my Response

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "account_type": "2",
    "car_data": [
        {
            "registration_no": "Lzq 2233",
            "engincc": "600 - 999",
            "enginccID": "1",
            "vehicleID": "32",
            "history": [
                {
                    "packages": "",
                    "date_time": "2018-12-22 00:40:55",
                    "bill_amount": "7098",
                    "bill_discount": "133.0571251",
                    "bill_paid": "36070"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "registration_no": "ghfdhhh",
            "engincc": "1500 - 1799",
            "enginccID": "3",
            "vehicleID": "33",
            "history": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is My Model

```
struct VehicleDataModel {
    var registrationNo : String?
    var engineCC: String?
    var engineCCID: String?
    var vehicleID: String?
    var history: [HistoryModel]


    struct HistoryModel {
        var packages: String
        var billDiscount : String
        var dateTime: String
        var billPaid: String
        var billAmount: String
    }
}
```

This is my Call API Function:

```
func callApi() {
    let url = "http://esspk.net/production/20m/Api/getVehicleApi"
    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "user_id")
    let param = ["user_id" : userID]
    print(param)
    ServerCall.makeCallWitoutFile(url, params: param, type: Method.POST, currentView: nil) { (response) in
        if let json = response {
            print(json)
            if let carData = json["car_data"].array
            {
                //let vehicalObj = VehicleDataModel()

                for cData in carData {

                    let regNo = cData["registration_no"].string
                    let enginCC = cData["engincc"].string
                    let enginID = cData["enginccID"].string
                    let vehicleID = cData["vehicleID"].string

                    let history = cData["history"].arrayObject
//                  let vech = VehicleDataModel(registrationNo: regNo, engineCC: enginCC, engineCCID: enginID, vehicleID: vehicle, history: history)
                    // self.vehicalModel.append(vech)
//                  let vech = VehicleDataModel.init(registrationNo: regNo, engineCC: enginCC, engineCCID: enginID, vehicleID: vehicleID, history: VehicleDataModel.HistoryModel( )                         
                }
                self.myVehicleTblView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+JSON). Parsing JSON is one of the most frequently asked questions. And you are encouraged to use the `Decodable` protocol.

Comment: `"History": "None"`? Who created the API? Why didn't he just use `null`?

Comment: history contain an array dictionary object  or else contain string of None .. 
i am confused how to separately implement ..

Answer (score 0):

First Make Model Class.

```
class Welcome: Codable {
    let response, accountType: String
    let carData: [CarDatum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response
        case accountType = "account_type"
        case carData = "car_data"
    }

    init(response: String, accountType: String, carData: [CarDatum]) {
        self.response = response
        self.accountType = accountType
        self.carData = carData
    }
}

class CarDatum: Codable {
    let registrationNo, engincc, enginccID, vehicleID: String
    let history: HistoryUnion

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case registrationNo = "registration_no"
        case engincc, enginccID, vehicleID, history
    }

    init(registrationNo: String, engincc: String, enginccID: String, vehicleID: String, history: HistoryUnion) {
        self.registrationNo = registrationNo
        self.engincc = engincc
        self.enginccID = enginccID
        self.vehicleID = vehicleID
        self.history = history
    }
}

enum HistoryUnion: Codable {
    case historyElementArray([HistoryElement])
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([HistoryElement].self) {
            self = .historyElementArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(HistoryUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for HistoryUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .historyElementArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

class HistoryElement: Codable {
    let packages, dateTime, billAmount, billDiscount: String
    let billPaid: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case packages
        case dateTime = "date_time"
        case billAmount = "bill_amount"
        case billDiscount = "bill_discount"
        case billPaid = "bill_paid"
    }

    init(packages: String, dateTime: String, billAmount: String, billDiscount: String, billPaid: String) {
        self.packages = packages
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.billAmount = billAmount
        self.billDiscount = billDiscount
        self.billPaid = billPaid
    }
}
```

Or you can also Use below Class

```
struct Welcome {
    let response, accountType: String
    let carData: [CarDatum]
}

struct CarDatum {
    let registrationNo, engincc, enginccID, vehicleID: String
    let history: HistoryUnion
}

enum HistoryUnion {
    case historyElementArray([HistoryElement])
    case string(String)
}

struct HistoryElement {
    let packages, dateTime, billAmount, billDiscount: String
    let billPaid: String
}
```

Then I recommended to use the Alamofire for Call the API.

```
func request() {

        let url = URL(string: "my url")
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON {(response) in

            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Welcome].self, from: data)
                        self.arrList = response
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //Print Responce
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            case .failure( let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This Works.

Comment: Can you Explain little ?

Comment: What you want to UnderStand?

Comment: Model class brother

Comment: Try to use online tool to create the model Class instead of manually. You can try https://app.quicktype.io/ to create the Class just by Pasting your JSON response .

Comment: Model class is created now how to access their values ?

Comment: look at the Alamofire request I append value `[Welcome].self` into class. You just simply have to print the data. By creating One variable